# How can I slide a vertical SeekBar in a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-event

I've made a vertical SeekBar by overriding the onDraw method and flipping it 90 degrees.
Now I need to put this in a ScrollView.

The actual layout structure is

```
<ScrollView>
  <RelativeLayout>
     ...
     <LinearLayout>
       <com.mypackage.VerticalSeekBar/>
```

Is it possible to make sure the ScrollView does not get the touch event of my seekbar?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this approach**

```
<ScrollView  
focusable="false" 
focusableInTouchMode="false" >
```

And in

```
<LinearLayout or in VerticalSeekBar
focusable="true" 
focusableInTouchMode="true" >
```

> It will stop ScrollView from getting focus and focus is get by VerticalSeekbar.